# Enter Mutex error for Launch4J

Tags: java, launch4j

What is the following error I get in `Launch4J` while converting my `Jar` file to an `Exe`:

```
Enter Mutex Name?
```

I am using Version 3.8 of `Launch4J`. Comment if you want me to elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you chose a Mutex, you allow only one instance of your application.

You can chose a random Mutex name, example: abcMutex0

**Without Mutex:**

[image: WithoutMutex]

**With Mutex:**

[image: WithMutex]

If you get the error `Enter Mutex Name?`, you may have tick "Allow only a single instance of the application" but you haven't enter a Mutex name.